# Retina display tilemap collision detection in cocos2d iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have created two different `tilemap`s for simple display and retina display.
Simple display collision detection is proper. When I test it on retina display map display properly but collision detection is not proper.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: You might be suffering with the same problem i think. Please [check link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710268/box2d-custom-polygon-and-sprites-mis-matching) whether it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I check for collisions using this function then it runs well in both displays.

```
- (CGPoint)tileCoordForPosition:(CGPoint)position 
{
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    NSLog(@"%f",map1.tileSize.height);
    int y = ((map1.mapSize.height * map1.tileSize.height) - position.y*scale) / map1.tileSize.height+(map1.position.y *scale/map1.tileSize.height);
    int x =-((map1.position.x *scale) / map1.tileSize.width)+(MainCharacter.position.x*scale/map1.tileSize.width);
    return ccp(x, y);
}
```